# Asp.Net State Server Service should RUN in all production web servers?

Tags: session, state, mode, session-state-server

Asp.Net 2.0 Session State Mode =  State Server and poiniting to the 1st server only in all webservers web.config

My Doubt

We have 6 production servers for our project. Do I need to make sure the Asp.Net State Server Service should RUN in all the 6 web servers? (or) It should be RUN only in 1st server?